# @Resource Injections in Weld SE

Tags: weld

I have a bean with `@Resource`-annotated field:

```scala
@ApplicationScoped
open class UtilProducer {    
    ...    

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/mj2")
    private lateinit var dataSource: DataSource

    ...
```

And I want to make Weld inject something into this `dataSource` field.

I tried to add my own implementation of `ResourceInjectionServices` - a `MyResourceInjectionServices`, but it doesn't seemed that it tries even to instantiate my class

```scala
val weld = Weld()
        .disableDiscovery()
        .addPackages(true, UtilProducer::class.java)
        .addPackages(true, CDIViewProvider::class.java)
        .addBeanClass(MyResourceInjectionServices::class.java)
```

How should I configure Weld SE to inject `@Resource`-annotated fields?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found in documentation that in such cases I need to subclass a `Weld` object. and override a `createDeployment` method:

```java
 public class MyWeld extends Weld {
     protected Deployment createDeployment(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, CDI11Bootstrap bootstrap) {
         return super.createDeployment(new MyResourceLoader(), bootstrap);
     }
 }
```

In my case in Kotlin in looks:

```
val weld = object : Weld() {
    override fun createDeployment(resourceLoader: ResourceLoader?, bootstrap: CDI11Bootstrap?): Deployment {
        val deployment = super.createDeployment(resourceLoader, bootstrap)
        deployment.services.add(ResourceInjectionServices::class.java, MyResourceInjectionServices())
        return deployment
    }
}.apply {
    disableDiscovery()
    addPackages(true, UtilProducer::class.java)
    addPackages(true, CDIViewProvider::class.java)
}
```